# Printing with a custom font in JavaFX

Tags: css, macos, javafx, printing, fonts

I have a custom font in my application. It's bundled and renders just find on my screen forms.

However, when I print, the font is not being used by the printer. It's also not being used if a I "save to PDF", which is built in to macOS.

I have this is my `root.css` file:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: "PT Serif";
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    src: url("fonts/PTSerif-Regular.ttf");
}
```

And I have this in my printing code:

```
PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

if (job != null && job.showPrintDialog(null)) {
    Printer printer = job.getPrinter();
    PageLayout pageLayout = printer.createPageLayout(Paper.NA_LETTER, PageOrientation.LANDSCAPE, Printer.MarginType.DEFAULT);

    Pane pane = getView(pageLayout.getPrintableWidth(), pageLayout.getPrintableHeight());
    pane.getStylesheets().add(getRootCSSURLString());
    boolean success = job.printPage(pageLayout, pane);
    if (success) {
        job.endJob();
    }
}
```

The CSS code works fine everywhere else. In fact, I know the CSS is working for the print job, as I changed the font size. It sees that, but it does not render the font.

I should also note that the PDF size is no different than before I used the custom font, so it's clear none of the font is being embedded in to the PDF either.

(I don't know how mac Printing works, I assume it renders everything into a PDF internally, thus being able to save it, and then "prints" it.)

Comment: Is the `Pane` part of a `Scene`? If not, what happens if you call `pane.applyCss(); pane.layout();` before printing it (but after adding the stylesheet, of course)?

Comment: Some suggestions using Font Book are [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/145498/20589).

Comment: @trashgod Yea, thank you, but that's not helpful in this case, as the reason I'm embedding a font in the first place is because the default JavaFX fonts (at least on macOS) are awful. For example, they don't even have a default BOLD for SanSerif. So, I'm bundling the font to force the issue and use that font "everywhere". Which means I want to use the same font on Mac, Linux, and Windows. So, I can't assume to have users install fonts in their machines just for my app.

Comment: @Slaw I did what you suggested and it...sort of worked. It worked with some layouts, but failed with others. If I add the Pane directly to a Scene, I get the font. But the layout is a wreck. If I wrap it in another container, add that to a scene, the layout is perfect, but the font is gone. I'm going to try more black box testing along those lines, see if I can find a layout scheme that works. Thanks.

Comment: This might be a bug. Consider submitting a report is one doesn't already exist (though I don't know if this would be high priority).